# Using ActiveAdmin in Rails to create user specific admin pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, rails-admin

To explain it in a sentence, I am asking if it is possible to use the ActiveAdmin gem to create admin pages specific to admin users, i.e. each admin user only gets to see models and associating models specific to him. If so, how would I implement this?

To further explain my situation, I have a model called Sponsor(who would essentially be the admin users), and they put up different offers(another model that belongs to Sponsor) for users to redeem. So what I am trying to do is create an admin page where each sponsor gets his own admin credentials, and the admin page only shows the information that relates to this sponsor, i.e. the information regarding the offers this sponsor put up, and all relating models and its details. Is this possible to implement using the ActiveAdmin gem or any other gems for that matter?

I would rather not implement this from scratch if there are gems out there that I could use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but it should be easily achievable in `ActiveAdmin`
either by changing the [default scope](http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages.html#index-scopes) on per controller basis or by using [AuthorizationAdapter](http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#scoping-collections-in-authorization-adapters).